# Difference between import and variable when Data Binding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

After reviewing [Data Binding documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#imports_variables_and_includes) on the difference between `<import/>` and `<variable/>`, it's unclear how they differ. Below are examples taken from the documentation page.

```
<import type="com.example.real.estate.View" alias="Vista"/>
```

looks like the equivalent of

```
<variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
```

except that an `alias` can start with a capital letter, while `name` cannot. They are even used similarly.

```
<data>
    <import type="com.example.MyStringUtils"/>
    <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
</data>
…
<TextView
   android:text="@{MyStringUtils.capitalize(user.lastName)}"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

The only difference I'm seeing, from the examples, are that you can call an `import`'s methods, but not a `variable`'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `variable` if you want to pass some data to views. In your example, you have user variable which is of type User and you use it to set users name in `TextView`. You can call variables methods - `user.lastName` is equivalent to `user.getLastName()`

With `import` you only specify class that you want to use, you don't pass any data. In your example, the imported utility class is used only to capitalize users name, which the `capitalize` method receives as an argument.